# Struts2 duplicate post values validation

Tags: validation, post, struts2

This question may seem a bit strange but thats the conclusion I have after few hours working on my problem :
It appears that when my form submit 2 times the same POST parameter (I see that using tamper data on firefox, I have 2 times the parameter id = xxx) struts automatically redirect to result "input" without even calling my action method (I don't have any prepare method in it).

Are you aware of such a thing (eg an interceptor) that prevent duplicate post values ?

Thanks, I hope im clear enough :(

Comment: You need to provide more details about your problem else its hard to say anything

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring and explicitly defining your action as a bean it needs to be "prototype" scope.

Other than that, no, there's nothing in S2 that would submit the same form value twice if it's only in the form once. This issue is almost always caused by a GET form and a singleton action.

If that's *not* the answer then you'll need to provide much more detail.

Comment: Im not using spring.
My question is not about how it comes that parameter appears twice but why when I submit 2 times the same parameter in the same post request then struts automatically redirect to INPUT without calling my action method.

Comment: @Estragon Probably because you're trying to set a collection onto a single property. Impossible to know without any information.